# Emulate GL_EYE_LINEAR with GL_OBJECT_LINEAR

Tags: opengl

I would like to use opengl texture to place a bitmap image to an object [1] and then fix it to the object [2]: just like a sticker.

The GL_EYE_LINEAR mode is nice to move my object in front of my 'sticker' [1], but how can I fix this 'sticker' on my object [2] (just after a button event or whatever) and then I'll continue into the  GL_OBJECT_LINEAR mode...

I try to "emulate" GL_EYE_LINEAR with GL_OBJECT_LINEAR mode during phase [1] with the modification of the GL_TEXTURE matrix, according with rotations/translations of GL_MODELVIEW matrix but still not have the same behavior of GL_EYE_LINEAR mode...

ps: I need to use GL_OBJECT_LINEAR to retrieve the x,y,z and rot(x,y,z) of my sticker texture.

Comment: Chuck all that deprecated stuff in the bin, and derive your own texture coordinates. Then you can make it work however you like.

Comment: Yes, you're (probably) right... but I need modify a python project (industrial software, no animation, no complex shader...) and I've, right now, not one month to rebuild the OpenGL part...
Anyway, have you a good web-tutorial to learn 'modern' OpenGL for a old fashion guy like me?

Comment: There are some resources listed in the info and the FAQ for the OpenGL tag.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm probably the only one trying to emulate GL_EYE_LINEAR with GL_OBJECT_LINEAR, but I finally found a way to do it.

First, the aim is to use a bitmap texture to stick on a model, so you have to save the current rotation (rx,ry,rz) and translation (tx,ty,tz) where you need to stick your texture/bitmap,  SAVE_POSITION= (rx_save,ry_save,rz_save,tx_save,ty_save,tz_save).

Then you have only to do the following steps:

0- gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW), gl.glLoadIdentity()

1- then modify de modelview matrix with this strict sequence:
   a. rotation(CURRENT_POSITION)
   b. translation(CURRENT_POSITION)
   c. translation(-SAVE_POSITION)
   d. rotation(-SAVE_POSITION)

2- Set the Texture generation (to place the bitmap texture):

```
gl.glTexGendv(gl.GL_S,gl.GL_EYE_PLANE,(self.TexSize,0,0,0))
gl.glTexGendv(gl.GL_T,gl.GL_EYE_PLANE,(0,self.TexSize,0,0))
gl.glTexGeni(gl.GL_S,gl.GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE,gl.GL_EYE_LINEAR)
gl.glTexGeni(gl.GL_T,gl.GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE,gl.GL_EYE_LINEAR)
gl.glEnable(gl.GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S)
gl.glEnable(gl.GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T)
```

3- reload the MODELVIEW gl.glLoadIdentity() (or use push/pop)
4- Rotate/translate to the CURRENT_POSITION as usual
5- draw your model

Hope it helps someone.

But as Jason said, the best way is to use the shaders not the legacy opengl...
I found some good tutorial for python programmers here:
http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/

regards,
-baco